# Covering intake register for a whole house fan in winter

Tags: vent, register

The register for the whole house fan blows cold air in winter from the attic.

I would like to cover it up to avoid this. I have seen HomeDepot/Lowes sell magnetic covers. However reviews indicate that they do not hold too well in that they peel off on their own.

Anyone have suggestions on solutions that you have used?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it safe to assume that this cold air problem occurs without the whole house fan being on? I can't think of any reason why one would turn a whole house fan on in the winter.

Answer (score 1):

Your register should not be "blowing cold air" regardless of the time of year. That indicates that you have a ducting problem, likely a popped duct seam somewhere. That could be costing you a LOT of money and should be found and fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comment. You are right. I need to review why air is blowing out through this register.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone into the attic and placed foam sheathing board over the vent ; removing the belt so the fan could not run. But now I am getting old and in our mild climate it doesn't seem necessary anymore.